# .NET Framework : Detect when a process prevent the screen saver

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, screensaver

In my .net Framework 4.6.1 application, i need to detect if a process prevent the screen saver.

I found the [SetThreadExecutionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate?redirectedfrom=MSDN) method. With this method, we can tell to Windows that our process prevent the screen saver. But in my case, i want to get if any process prevent the screen saver.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Neither SPI_GETSCREENSAVEACTIVE nor HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\DesktopScreenSaveActive work on my Windows 10-x64... Set to TRUE and 1 even if system disabled.

Comment: https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/318781

Comment: `SetThreadExecutionState()` is kind of a *simplified* way to call [PowerCreateRequest()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-powercreaterequest) + [PowerSetRequest()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-powersetrequest). The former returns just the previous state. The other returns a Handle of the request. Now, the Handle is opaque, it cannot be used directly and, AFAIK, the System only keeps a reference count of the requests generated for each type, so there's probably no direct way to make a reverse lookup query.

Comment: So you (probably) have to test whether a Process has an open Handle of the Type you're looking for, something like Sysinternals' [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) does. So, open the Process, call `NtQuerySystemInformation()`, `NtDuplicateObject()` to set the access level and `NtQueryObject()`, assuming you can get the desired access. -- Can you say why you need this information? Maybe there's another, more direct - managed - way.

Comment: Olivier, in my case, SPI_GETSCREENSAVEACTIVE it's not working, because i need to check processes prevent the screen saver in Windows & Windows RDS environment and this kind of method not working correctly on this type of environment (screensaver is obscure in RDS)

Comment: Jimi, i need this information to check if there is a conf call (like Teams or other) to not perform an action in my app.
The solution has to work on Windows & Windows RDS env.
If SetThreadExecutionState() return the previous value, i think i can use it to do this ?

Comment: Nope, `SetThreadExecutionState()` returns the state of the calling Thread, your Thread. It tells you nothing about other Threads that may have set the same (or similar) mode. It can be used to check the current state, since this function must be called periodically to preserve the selected mode and keep it active, otherwise the System just resets (after a Timeout) the normal mode. -- Check the [CallNtPowerInformation()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powerbase/nf-powerbase-callntpowerinformation) function, the `InformationLevel` param can be set to `SystemExecutionState`.

Comment: Note that I'm not sure this will return a value that reliably references a specific state, or it's instead a *general* information. You'll have to test whether it's enough for your use case.